# Solve sinusoidal function algebraically

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry, problem-solving

Can someone give me a hint on the following question
solve the sinusoidal function that have a y value that is 1 unit greater than its minimum during the first two cycles of function

$Y=-1.2(\cos(-0.99x)-6)+4.45$

I have found out the minimum of this function which is $-3.95$

1. I'm not getting how this function has $2$ cycles ?
2. If we already know the value of $Y$ (which should be $-2.95$ I think), then what are we going to solve?

Comment: I found that the minimum of the given function is $10.45$ (and maximum $12.85$), by trying $\cos(-0.99x) = \pm 1$.

Comment: Oh yeah you are right.just edited. But can you explain my other two questions as well ??

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "this function has $2$ cycles." The cosine function only has one period, $2\pi$.